# Converting an Array of HTML Elements to Nodelist

Tags: javascript, arrays, dom, nodelist

I'm writing a function for swapping the position of child elements in a parent element.

```
<div class="parent">
    <div class="first-child"></div>
    <div class="second-child"></div>
</div>
```

So I'm getting the children of .parent turning the Nodelist into an array, reordering the array to swap the order / position of the elements i.e first-child, second-child becomes second-child, first-child - This all works perfectly. However, ideally the function will return the parent element with the reordered structure, but because I effectively spliced the nodelist into an array the elements in the array are no longer considered 'nodes' meaning I get an error when attempting to append it as a child to the parent.

So, how can I convert an array of elements back into a Nodelist as I understand that a Nodelist is not native to javascript?

Here's a Codepen of what I have so far. http://codepen.io/anon/pen/QNPKqB?editors=0011

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The error in your code isn't that you need a NodeList, it's that you've named both a function and an element swap.

```
var parent = document.querySelector('.swap');
swap(parent, first, second);
```

Is what you need

I don't have a codepen account so instead, see the working code here:
https://jsfiddle.net/owr15hnf/

Comment: Oh sorry! I actually renamed the variables in the Codepen to something more relevant before I posted it here - The example in Codepen actually works, but when I use it in another environment It throws up the Node error.

Comment: The environment is on a site I'm currently building and the error is the type error - however, my question is more; how can I redefine the type of an array of elements to a Nodelist as opposed the the actually error itself, I know what is causing it and how to get around it i.e. just append the elements  to the innerHTML of the parent. But if there's a way to convert the array back to a Nodelist that'd be awesome!

Comment: You cannot convert your array into a NodeList so that is definitely not the solution.

Answer (score 0):

This is how you can convert HTML to node list,

```
    const targetElement = document.getElementById('targetElement');

    const htmlElementsArray = Array.from(targetElement.children).map(el => el.outerHTML)
    // htmlElementsArray contains an array of HTML Elements.

    console.log(htmlElementsArray,'ArrayList.')
    
    const nodeList = new DOMParser().parseFromString([htmlElementsArray].join(''), "text/html").body.childNodes;
    // nodeList is the converted Html list to node list

    console.log(nodeList,'nodeList')
```

You can find the example here: https://codepen.io/furki911/pen/qByzdXm?editors=1111